# How to get the array of object(song) to store in a variable

Tags: react-native

I want the url from the data to pass in the music player to play the song.
I'm unable to setState url in the song[] state.

```
componentWillMount(){
      var ur_i = this.props.navigation.getParam('uri');
   console.log(JSON.stringify(ur_i));

       this.setState(this.state.song=ur_i)
       alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.song.url))
    }
```

[image: This is data which is coming to from the server and store in ur_i]

I want song Url to be store in the song[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid `setState` usage method.

`setState()` operates asynchronously.

> setState(updater[, callback])

The callback function of `setState(updater[, callback])` is performed and is re-renderable.

**Example**

```js
timerAction = () => {
    const { time } = this.state;
    console.log(time);
this.setState({
      time: time - 1
    })
    console.log(time)
  };
```

**Usage**

```js
componentDidMount(){
      var ur_i = this.props.navigation.getParam('uri');
   console.log(JSON.stringify(ur_i));

       this.setState(song:ur_i[0].song,() => alert(JSON.stringify(ur_i[0].song)))

    }
```

Comment: its worked with little bit edit Here is the edited code. ```this.setState({song:ur_i[0].song})
       alert(JSON.stringify(ur_i[0].song));```